# how to show integer, not float, with hover tooltip in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a simple graph of X-Y data points.  I want my Bokeh figure to show me the integer value of each datapoint when I hover over it.  I am close to getting what I want but when I hover over the data point, it shows a float and then higher up, it uses scientific notation.  Is there a way to have the hover tool only return the integer values of X and Y and not use scientific notation?

Here is some example code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

x = range(1,101)
y = [i*i for i in x]

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select, hover"

p = figure(x_axis_label = "Days",
       y_axis_label = "Return",
       tools=TOOLS)
p.circle(x, y)

#adjust what information you get when you hover over it
hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Days", "$x"),
    ("Return", "$y"),
]

show(VBox(p))
```

Answer (score 44):

Adding my two cents. I figured out by you can control the decimal points by using the following code:

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Days", "@x{int}"), # this will show integer, even if x is float
    ("Return", "@y{1.11}"), # this will format as 2-decimal float
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will, curious if you know how to scale y and then format it. for example, let's say you want to multiply y by 100 and report as a percentage. any thoughts on how to specify that?

Comment: This is great. Do you know if there is notation for formatting dates like this? I didn't manage to find this in the documents; do you happen to have a link where this is located? Thanks!

Comment: @Chris sorry not aware of a flag for percentage formatting. I suppose you already tried Python's formatting flags? What I'd do is to create another column in your data source and plot that instead, not perfect but might get you there.

Comment: @ryanjdillon I think I found these in their Google Group archives. Unfortunately it's not in the docs as far as I know. I haven't chased down in the source code yet to find out how it's parsed but it's a bit different to the traditional python format strings. However, things like '+1.11' still works, i.e. puts a sign in front of numbers.

Answer (score 13):

Aha! Using @ instead of $ works.

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Days", "@x"),
    ("Return", "@y"),
]
```

Comment: yep `$x` is the built in canvas data point of the mouse pointer, `@x` is the actual data point no matter where you hover over the glyph.